# Warm up maven dependency cache

Tags: maven, caching, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

How can I warm up the dependency cache of my maven tests? E.g. `mvn test -DskipTests` downloads some of the dependencies, but not all, e.g. some of the maven surefire plugin dependencies are only downloaded by `mvn test`.

I want to create a snapshot of my filesystem to boost up the execution of my tests. Therefore I'd like to have all the dependencies downloaded, but I want to achieve this without executing the tests itself.

Some of the dependencies that are only downloaded during `mvn test` and not by `mvn test -DskipTests`:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit47/2.14/surefire-junit47-2.14.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-    junit47/2.14/surefire-junit47-2.14.pom (4 KB at 13.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-providers/2.14/surefire-providers-2.14.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dependencies are resolved on a need-by-need basis:

- The compile time ones for the application's code are downloaded as a very first step when you start the build.
- Any plugins required are downloaded afterwards during the respective phases. This also includes their transitive dependencies.
- The dependencies for the tests are downloaded when the tests are to be compiled and executed. These are the dependencies with `<scope>test</scope>`.

Therefore, at the point where you're at the `test` phase, you already must have the latest dependencies, unless you have them cached locally and installed and you're in offline mode.

To [resolve all your dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html), you can do:

`mvn dependency:go-offline`

To [resolve all the plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-plugins-mojo.html), you can do:

`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. My problem is that `mvn test -DskipTests` doesn't download surefire, only `mvn test` does. So I don't know how to warm up the local cache without executing the tests themselves.

Comment: Well, if you are not going to run the tests (which is what you're doing with `mvn test -DskipTests`), then Maven assumes you are only interested in compiling them, which, in term makes the downloading executing of the `maven-surefire-plugin` not necessary.

Comment: Ok, but then how can I prepare my tests to run in an offline environment?

Comment: Well, you need to (at least once) build with `mvn clean test` so that they are downloaded. Then you can go offline all you want.

Comment: You can also do: `mvn dependency:go-offline`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted. dependency:go-offline... and.... surefire is still not downloaded. :(( Worth a bug report? And I'll go with some workaround to execute some tests to get all the dependencies.

Comment: `mvn dependency:offline` only resolves your `compile` and `test`-scoped dependencies, it doesn't download plugins. You can further do: `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: mvn dependency:resolve-plugins is covered by mvn dependency:go-offline. I suspect that some of the surefire dependencies are determined only during running. (e.g. which junit to support.) +1 until I find any better.

Comment: Do let me know when (and if) you find an answer as I've had to deal with this before and it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: Selecting which JUnit to suppor in my pom file + mvn dependency:go-offline + mvn test -DskipTests did the trick. :)  [link] (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

maven surefire plugin gets downloaded only for mvn test because default Goal execution phase for this plugin is test.

I guess if you want to execute surefire plugin you can specify goal execution phase.

Comment: I want to pre-download surefire so a following `mvn test` doesn't download anything from the net. Changing an execution phase doesn't make a difference, I don't want to execute surefire.

Comment: execute `mvn test` at least one time. This would download dependencies, now next time you execute run `mvn test -o` instead of `mvn test`

Answer (score 0):

We have the following approach for filling the Maven cache on our Jenkins slaves:

- Do a full build
- Zip the `~/.m2` folder (which contains the cached instances)
- Place it and extract it on the machine where you want to run your "warmed-up" tests
- Automate steps above steps to keep it recent and up to date.

Comment: yikes........;p